# Read continuous data from serial port with pyserial

Tags: python, arduino, pyserial

I have strings being continuously sent from my arduino.

For example, I am sending an integer (0-1023) line by line, so it should be:

```
"51\r\n233\r\n37\r\n166\r\n"
```

And infinitely long as it is continuously streaming.

I am currently using `pyserial`'s function `readline()` to read the data, but constantly see broken/missing bytes. For example, instead of `"37\r\n"` followed with `"11\r\n"`, it will get `"3\r11\r\n"` or even `"3711\r\n"`!

Here's my full Python-end code:

```
import serial
import time

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ser = serial.Serial('COM3', baudrate=1000000)
    data = []
    time0 = time.time()
    while (time.time() - time0 < 5):  # Read data for 5 seconds
        data.append(ser.readline())
    ser.close()
```

For those interested, the (probably relevant) arduino code is simply:

```
#define FASTADC 1  // Flag for prescale 16
// Code pasted for modifying ADCSRA
#ifndef cbi
#define cbi(sfr, bit) (_SFR_BYTE(sfr) &= ~_BV(bit))
#endif
#ifndef sbi
#define sbi(sfr, bit) (_SFR_BYTE(sfr) |= _BV(bit))
#endif

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(1000000);
  #if FASTADC
    // set prescale to 16
    sbi(ADCSRA,ADPS2) ;
    cbi(ADCSRA,ADPS1) ;
    cbi(ADCSRA,ADPS0) ;
  #endif
}

void loop() {
  int val;
  val = analogRead(A0);
  Serial.println(val);
}
```

As you can see from the code, the baud rate, parity, stop bit were both set to 1,000,000; None; 1.

Comment: sounds like mismatching rate/parity/stop bit settings. make sure you use exactly the same on both ends. also try with lower speeds first.

Comment: @miraculixx Thank you! I should've included those info in the OP. The baud rate, parity, stop bit were both set to 1,000,000; None; 1.

Comment: as you noted, that was visible from the code, however, did you try with lower speed settings? Are you sure your Arduino and USB ports both support 1e6 baud/bps?

Comment: @miraculixx Good point... I tried lower speed settings and they are still there, just less frequently (because there're less data I guess). The Arduino community has confirmed that both Arduino and my USB port support 1e6 baud rate, in http://goo.gl/vwaOXy and http://goo.gl/Zb9fGe

Comment: @miraculixx Thanks for your help - I now narrowed it down to Arduino sending out serial data (I guess). I have a new progress http://goo.gl/wY4XYu  so probably we don't need to waste time on this thread anymore. Anyway, thanks for your help!